# Edges measurement - tool vs edges

Tags: edges, measurement

I'm really confused about the way measurements are displayed in Blender.

At first, I was using the Measure tool from the toolbar, which seem to show the right sizes, but at some random point, something changed.. I started looking at the sizes of the edges when scaling them, which seems accurate.

Now that I'm finished with the shape, size of the edge is completely different than the size shown by the measurement tool? What am I missing??

When comparing the edges for the Z-axis, the Measure tool actually gives similar values, so why would it be different for X and Y.

[image]

Here's another example - When I scale the edge, it shows me one size, but when I use the Measurement tool, other numbers appear.

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Shay

Comment: You have to apply the scale with Ctrl+A. If you scale the default 2×2×2 m cube in _Obkect Mode_ by 5, the **dimensions** are 10×10×10 m on the "outside", i.e. the global coordinate system. But if you go in _Edit Mode_ and select the edges, they are still 2 m. This is the original base **mesh size**, while the scale in _Object Mode_ is a factor to make it appear larger. When you apply the scale, the underlying mesh size is now converted to the scaled size as being original, that's why the scale is reset from 5 to 1.

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/218403/35559

Comment: Do you mean you scaled your object in *Object Mode*? Measure Tool shows you the Object Mode size ([your real mesh size * object scale](https://i.imgur.com/DlrVaGo.png)) , while *Edge Length* in Edit Mode shows you the "real", original dimensions of your mesh. They'll match if you apply your scale: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/28558/71578 Is this it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the Measure tool doesn't update dynamically if you alter geometry, you'd have to use the show Edge Length overlay as mentioned and linked here. You could also look into the shipped add-on called Meaure It. With this tool you can set a measurement segment between two vertices or on an edge e.g. that will update dynamically if you alter the geometry, you can also use this tool to include measurements in your render ... it's a pretty complex tool, find a tutorial and spend a few hours getting to know it if it's useful for you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. As a beginner, these concepts are very vague to me and hard to grasp. I applied the scale with CTRL+A and nothing happened. Is this fixable or do I need to start over and pay closer attention to sizes in object mode?

Comment: Oh, now I see it... measurements have been updated.. I managed to adjust the sizes with the scale tool. Thank you all!